# POSIX and PCRE compliant regex to extract a word

Tags: regex, pcre, posix-ere

I want to extract a string whether it is at the beginning of a sentence or the end it has to be the whole word. The expression should work in both PCRE and POSIX.

Example:

```
input strings=['ALLY [&] MORTY','[&] ME', '[&]']
---> match is in bracket
```

Comment: Are the brackets actually in the string?

Answer (score 0):

```
(^| )(&)( |$)
```

- `(^| )` matches either the beginning of the string or a space
- `(&)` matches the literal string `&`.
- `( |$)` matches either a space or the end of the string.

The match will be in capture group 1.